# How to Instantly Lock your Mac OS X Screen, using keyboard, in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, screen, screen-lock

I have a Macbook Air, and I want to know if there is a way to instantly lock my screen, using only my keyboard.

I saw that it is possible to lock it using the following shortcut: `Control+Shift+Eject`.

But since Macbook Air didn't have an `Eject` key, how could I still lock my screen using a similar shortcut?