# Is it possible to program an OS X screen lock?

Tags: security

I want the ability to lock my Macbook at my command. I don't want a screensaver or sleep lock. Don't you get tired of repeatedly typing in your password in all day? I don't want to wait for my computer to lock itself in 10 minutes or 1 minute when the screensaver or sleep begins. I don't want to save and close all my apps and documents and logout.

So just let me lock my computer, simple request. Hit a hotkey? Close the lid?

I walk out my door, I lock my door. I get out of my car, I lock my car. Why can't I just lock my computer?

I've been told you can't reconfigure this type of setting in OS X, is this true?

Comment: Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver -> Screen Saver -> Hot Corners

Comment: Since this got migrated in, would you review some of our questions to indicate if they answer your question? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac?rq=1 http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82360/how-to-instantly-lock-your-mac-os-x-screen-using-keyboard-in-mountain-lion http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/is-there-a-similarly-fast-alternative-to-crtl-shift-eject-for-new-macbook-th

Comment: thanks bmike, my searches didn't turn those up, I suppose I will be more thorough in the future.  Great posts, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On a Macbook, pressing ctrl+shift+Eject will lock the screen instantly.  These keyboard shortcuts are configurable from System Preferences.

Comment: Control-shift-power just powers off the screen on my MacBook Pro - so you'll need additional settings like a password lock screen that requires a password immediately for this to be a good instant lock.

Comment: thanks, but so far these solutions are dependent on screensaver/sleep locks, which I don't care for.  I want to circumvent the incessant entering of my password for every 5 minutes I'm away.  Just want to lock and unlock on my own terms.

Comment: How about disabling the screen saver lock, and setting your security preferences to require an unlock when the system comes out of sleep?